# WZZIP not excluding files in @listfile process

Tags: batch-processing, winzip

I'm using a batch file and I'm trying to exclude a list of folders inside a list file but they get added anyway. Any help will be appreciated.

```
This is what I have tried so far:

wzzip -i -r F:\Backup\Docs.zip C:\Users\Tory\Documents\*.* -x@exclude.txt

This is the contents of the list file named exclude.txt:
```

Bioware*.*
"Diablo II*.*"
"My Games*.*"